# Indexing PDFs in solr4 No Docs Returned on search

Tags: apache, solr, apache-tika

I am quite new to Solr. Trying to use solr-cell to index pdf files.

Using : DataImportHandler

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">tika-data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
```

tika-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
<document>
    <entity name="tika-test" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
            url="C:/solr-4.9.0/contrib/extraction/src/test-docs/extraction/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.9.pdf" format="text">
            <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
            <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
            <field column="text" name="text"/>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Schema.xml

```
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

After I run data import handler from solr admin, it says processed 1 documents, Updated one document. Thats fine since I am providing only one file

But when I execute search with q as *:* in solr admin, it gives me the following

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {}
    ]
  }
```

I am not sure what I am missing, I could not find anything using solr documents. This is pretty simple example, so if all conf is correct it should ve worked :(

Comment: check whats the defaultsearch field in your schema.xml...Or try by searching on a specific field like q=text:"abc"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit after indexing document. or reload core or restart Solr

(refer below URL, change URL names according to you)

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to troubleshoot these is to uncomment/define dynamic field * with type string (stored and indexed). That way every field that you got through the configuration will show up. Once that part is correct, you go back and fine-tune your import definitions and schema.